# check if a field value exit in array - MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nosql

I'm using MongoDB and i have the following schema of person collection:

```
Person {
    age: [number]
}
```

i want to check if the age of a person exist in array, for exemple [15, 20, 12, 0]. i need something like **$in** operator but in reverse.

**schema:**

```
initiatives : {
    ressources: [
        { departement: ObjectId }
        { departement: ObjectId }
    ]
)
```

Comment: check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32344017/check-if-field-exists-in-an-sub-document-of-an-array?answertab=active#tab-top

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [$expr](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/index.html) with [$in](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/in/index.html):

```
Person.find({ $expr: { $in: [ "$age", [15, 20, 12, 0] ] } })
```

EDIT: to compare arrays you need [$setIntersection](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setIntersection/) and [$size](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/index.html) operators, try:

```
Person.find({
    $expr: {
        $gt: [
            {
                $size: {
                    $setIntersection: [
                        [
                        "15",
                        "a",
                        "12",
                        "0"
                        ],
                        "$age.x"
                    ]
                }
            },
            0
        ]
    }
})
```

Comment: SyntaxError: identifier starts immediately after numeric literal

Comment: @Ayoubk I don't see your code but this is what I meant: https://mongoplayground.net/p/vWTttH-dDXA

Comment: yes it works in your example. anyway i have the following query `db.initiatives.find({ $expr: { $in: [ "$ressources.function", [5c3da236248330595ab337db] ] } })`

Comment: Wrap `5c3da236248330595ab337db` with `"5c3da236248330595ab337db"` or `ObjectId("5c3da236248330595ab337db")`

Comment: `db.initiatives.find({ $expr: { $in: [ "$ressources.function", [ObjectId('5c3da236248330595ab337db')] ] } })`

Comment: So maybe you could paste sample document, input data and expected result to make it easier ? If think you still have the right tool shown ($in + $expr)

Comment: doesn't work here either : mongoplayground.net/p/tKWRGrFCBD8

Comment: You can use $setIntersection with $size for arrays on both sides, try: https://mongoplayground.net/p/NmU67SyePLO