# Mongo db : Query on array that matches any elemet of another passed array

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

There are documents like:

```
{ _id:1, color:['red', 'green', 'yellow'},
{ _id:2, color:['red', 'blue', 'orange'},
{ _id:3, color:['blue', 'black', 'grey'}
```

Now what I am trying to do is :
If I passed ['red']

It should return  document with id 1 and 2. If I passed ['black', 'yellow'], it should  return document with id 1 and 3.

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55106243/check-if-a-field-value-exit-in-array-mongodb/55106297#55106297 ?

Comment: No  it doesnot match my requirement. But this does somewhat. But not all my requirement and I couldnot modify it . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25318050/matching-an-array-field-which-contains-any-combination-of-the-provided-array-in

Comment: Well, I think that link I pasted is what you need, please take a look: https://mongoplayground.net/p/cniCK__p3XM

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [$elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) to get what you want.

**Try this:**

```
db.collection.find({
  color: {
    $elemMatch: {
      $in: [
        "black",
        "yellow"
      ]
    }
  }
})
```

Have a look at this [Mongo Playground demo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/yPFb1QB4Vqr), to play with the query.